# Angular-Get response posted to php url

Tags: angular

I have an angular app. I post data to a php api payment.php which in turn makes a request to payment gateway. One parameter of the request to payment gateway is a callback url which in this case is callback.php.

Steps:

When I post data from angular to payment.php a request is made to a payment gateway.
Payment gateway responds to payment.php if parameters are correct and shows payment is being processed (this part i am able to get as json in Angular).

After processing,payment gateway returns a response to callback.php as confirmation of succees or failure.

I am now stuck on how I can get the confirmation message from callback.php from my angular app.
How can I listen to callback.php and know when callback response is sent and retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Observables while creating a http request. When you use Observables, you can access multiple responses from the same api. Its like a event-subscription model. Read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#:%7E:text=Angular%20makes%20use%20of%20observables,variety%20of%20common%20asynchronous%20operations.&text=You%20can%20define%20custom%20events,handle%20AJAX%20requests%20and%20responses.)

Comment: I have not yet managed to get the response in confirmation.php.  How does angular listen if a php url has received a response and then get that response?

Comment: Are you saying that, after you have sent "Processing" message to the front end from payment gateway, you cannot call callback.php? I'm sorry, I got confused there a little bit. Could you explain what happens after you send the first response to Angular.